# Readfile() with warning error and html_entity_decode() not working - PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding, readfile

Im trying to use php for download a file from a ssh server. The download is working but i got a warning with my function readfile() and the characters keep in html style while i use this function html_entity_decode().

If i try this :`var_dump($output)` it gives me something like this string(xxx)" ". A string with xxx characters but empty.

The error :

```
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;ResultatPEC xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance&quot; dateCreation=&quot;02-12-2018&quot; versionFichier=&quot;0000842887&quot; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=&quot;Resultats_PEC_2.10.xsd&quot;&gt;
&lt;IdentificationDepot CodeOffre=&quot;0&quot; CodeSiteDepot=&quot;932930&quot; DateDepot=&quot;26-11-2018&quot; HeureDepot=&quot;07:04&quot; IDDeposant=&quot;590226&quot; NiveauService=&quot;E&quot; NumDepot=&quot;BR099441&quot; NumeroBip=&quot;0000793653&quot; NumSTP=&quot;21787924&quot; OptionDateDepot=&quot;DepotJourCreux&quot; OptionMeca=&quot;0&quot; OptionSiteDepot=&quot;Standard&quot; TypeDeclaration=&quot;DEPOT&quot; ZoneDense=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;
  &lt;Publication IDPCD=&quot;1174646&quot; NoPublication=&quot;0520K87314&quot; NoParution=&quot;391&quot; NoParutionConstate=&quot;391&quot; PublicationPanelisee=&quot;0&quot; TypeParution=&quot;NUM&quot; TypeParutionConstate=&quot;NUM&quot;&gt;
     in <b>D:\www\SAGAPEC\application\modules\supervision\controllers\AdminController.php</b> on line <b>397</b><br />
```

My code :

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($this->_configFile->ftp->hostname, $this->_configFile->ftp->port);
        if ($connection) {
            $login = ssh2_auth_password($connection, $this->_configFile->ftp->login, $this->_configFile->ftp->password);
            if ($login) {
                $content = true;
                if ($content) { 
                    $fileName = $this->_getParam('name');
                    if ($fileName){ 
                        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "cat {$fileName}");
                        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                        $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
                        simplexml_load_string($output); 
                        $abc = html_entity_decode($output,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");

                        $file = $abc; 

                        header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
                        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
                        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file)); 

                        readfile($file);
                        exit(); 
                    }
```

Comment: readfile expects the string to be a file path, you appear to be passing an XML string? Did you mean to simply `echo` the data?

Comment: Yes, all the files are XML files. The `echo $output` gives me nothing, only the `var_dump($output)` gives me something like this `string(1064) " "`.

Comment: I didn't ask if they were XML. You're not passing `readfile` a file path, yet that's what it needs. You can't give it an XML string and expect it to work. `basename` potentially isn't working right for you either.

Comment: You say it gives you nothing when you echo, have you tried looking at the view-source page? Is the XML there? Or has it tried to do a download?

Comment: Ok so what can i do for display a XML string? I have to change the function readfile() ?

Comment: Yes the XML is in the view-source page.

Comment: Also try changing `" . basename($file)` to just a static name.

Comment: The file is downloading correctly with the good name of the file. It recognise the XML file. But the warning still there and the encoding still in html characters.

Comment: You did remove the `readline` line, right?

Comment: `readline`? No i didnt remove it

Comment: If you've put the `echo` in just remove the `readline` since it's not doing anything.

Comment: Ok I already make it, but nothing is moving.

Comment: What do you mean? You now have XML downloading to a file, right?

Comment: I dont understand what's mean `readline` , is it the echo?

Comment: `readfile($file);` <-- this was in your code. Remove it, and replace with a single `echo $file;`. The `readline` was a typo :P

Comment: OMG, you are a pro, that's working perfectly.

Comment: Great. Apologies for the confusion there though :P.

Comment: Thanks for taking time with me @JonStirling

Comment: No that's was me :D thanks again !